# calculating the page load time on fly across different browser(C# console application preferbly if not any technology)

Tags: c#

Hey i need to have a console application (C#) which can take the screen shot of the page once it is loaded(in all the browser).How can i calculate the time taken for the page to load completely from my C# console applications.:)...the windows form control works with the ie8 only. Basically i need to be able to calculate the time taken for the page to load on fly from my console application and it should be applicable for the all the browsers.(i am able to find in the same in ie as webforms control by default uses ie8 for rendering the html file.

If it not possible with c# console application pls suggest any other way also.It can be in java also.

An eary reply is highly valued,

Thanks Sagar.

Comment: perhaps you should ask what exactly you want to achieve? (For example, are you trying to load testing your application?). I am not certain what exactly you want to measure here - is it time taken by request to do round-trip (i.e. request to server and get response) or time taken for page to load in browser since the response has arrived?

Answer (score 0):

Without actually interfering with the browser through an exposed API or an extension/add-on to a browser which can communicate to your console application, IMO this can be very hard or impossible. So find out whether the browser of your choice exposes an API to let you acquire the details or whether an extension can communicate with your console application.